# cant get CORS working in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, cors

Hello im trying to ajax cross domain call , but there is problem with headers. I followed many of tutorials but i just cant get it working.

This is how far did i go :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>

    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //this would be done in a common script file if you are going to
        //make a lot of these calls
        $.ajaxSetup({ type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json', data: {} });

        $('#btn').click(function() {
             //call the web service with the button is clicked
            $.ajax({ url: 'url_external',
                data: '{ "some_data:data" }', //ensure the data is enclosed in a quote
                            success: function (data) {
                alert('here...success');
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                alert('here');
            }
            });

            //return false to avoid a postback
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>


<div>
    <button id='btn'>Load It</button>
    <div id='sayit'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this only work in IE9. Am I missing something? In Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome there is problem with options and **405 Method not allowed**

Comment: The problem is your server is not handling the OPTIONS request.

Comment: And how to handle it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: thanks. Ill try it. But if you have some time. Can u edit my code to work with cors to mark it as answered? Thanks. Maybe it will help many people

Comment: You need server-side code.  Your question only contains client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to all of your HTTP responses on the `'url_external'` server:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

This enables [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) Ajax requests on your `url_external` server.

You'd probably want to fine tuned this to...

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com');
```

... in order to allow only CORS requests coming only from your domain.

The best information I found about CORS: [Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).