# Sending Ajax request with Basic Authentication and Raw data

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I m making ajax call like this :

```
            var username = "someusername";
            var password= "somepassword";

    var datam = '{"description":"my description","account":"mehame","username":"hakan","password":"11"}';

    $.ajax
            ({
                url: "http://mywebsite.com:8080/directory/send",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: datam,
                dataType: 'text',
                type: "PUT",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": btoa(username + ":" + password)
                  },
                beforeSend: function (){
                    //xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(username, password));
                    console.log(datam);
                },
                success: function (){
                    alert("Here's lots of data, just a string: " + datam);
                },
                error : function(){
                    alert("Here's lots of data, just a string: " + datam);
                }
            });

        });
```

And firebug console gave me "Cross Domain Error" (and returned error) :

"*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://mywebsite.com:8080/directory/send. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.*"

But in my chrome extensions name is "**[PostMan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/related)**" its completely working.

What is different?

Comment: Which programming language u use at backend?>

Comment: I m using java  at the backend

Comment: Then in your java file in backend , check for valid data(Usernm+pwd), If correct ,return True response to ajax else False.Its simpla

Comment: Its true. Work on the chrome extensions. But in html page doesn't work.

Comment: U use JSP correct?Please tell why it doesnt work.

Comment: No I m not using JSP or JSF. I M using plain html. In My backend I m using java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16380492/1385672

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ okey I understand and I know CORS Policy. But, chrome extensions working successfully, how?

Comment: @mehmetakifalp - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr - `Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.`

Answer (score 0):

Due to same-origin policy, you can't execute ajax request on a foreign hostname or port number.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

You must enable CORS in your http headers : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You can also see this post to know how to do that : [cant get CORS working in chrome and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133562/cant-get-cors-working-in-chrome-and-firefox)